# How to override css within Drupal content area using a div

Tags: css, drupal

I want to force all the html within a div to be the same font size and line spacing. The html includes

and  elements. I tried to simply use inline styling for the div, e.g.

```
<div style="font-size: .75em;">
 <p>blah</p>
 <ul>
  <li>blah2</li>
 </ul>
 <p>blah 3</p>
</div>
```

but the stylesheet causes the p and li to be larger fonts. This leads to my putting more inline styles in to each line and that is just not right.

I do not have access to the stylesheet, so I have to whatever I do here inline. I just need a code snippet to give authors (the content is inside Drupal) so they can accomplish this task without having to push a new site css file.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the size in pixels, the child elements should inherit the set size. For this to work you would also have to use the "Full HTML" filter option for the textarea field.

```
<div style="font-size: 12px;">
 <p>blah</p>
 <ul>
  <li>blah2</li>
 </ul>
 <p>blah 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, that has no effect...here is my div tag 
`<div id="NaturalGas" style="display:none; border: 1px solid gray; padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px; background-color:#B3D0ED; font-size: 8px; line-height: 100%;">`
(display none is b/c this is part of jquery toggle)

Comment: Not easy to say what works and not, not knowing what styles are in effect, but you could try with `font-size: 8px !important;`. Otherwise you could (if possible) change the html structure so you don't inherit anything, e.g. using `<div>` instead of `<p>` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS of your site theme is probably setting the style on the 'p' or the 'ul' or the 'li' elements so even though your div defines the style inline, it is still being overridden by the more global CSS file. Use firebug or Chrome tools to see which .css file is setting the style, the define your local override styles at the same level (e.g. on the p or ul or li elements).